# Do I need to create folders in cloudinary?

Tags: cloudinary

I am building an new web application and want to use Cloudinary for users' images. My question is that do I need to create folders in my Cloudinary cloud? The reason I am asking is that if I were using a file system and start having 100,000+ images in one folder, it will start killing my app, and I would need to break then into several folders.

Is it the same for Cloudinary?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your current and future requirements.
In general, I believe that folders can help with better organizing your resources, especially when there are lots of them.
Note that besides folders, you can also assign tags to your images (e.g., by user) or add a prefix to the images' public IDs (e.g., `user1-<image_name>`).
You can later use Cloudinary's Admin API to list your resources either by folder/prefix or by tag.

Comment: Well said about the organization. But what about performance ?

Comment: What aspect of performance are your worried about? Image delivery?

Comment: Exactly, image delivery. I am afraid that performance will go down (become slow) once I have a large number of images ..

Comment: Performance in image delivery will not be affected whether you have dozens of images or millions. Cloudinary is a very strong and stable service. Besides, Cloudinary uses Akamai's CDN to deliver all resources, Akamai is widely considered as the best CDN around.